# Как работать с pdo используя namecpase

Tags: php, pdo, namespace

В видео-уроке используют mysqli, я же решил работать с pdo, но возник вопрос - как использовать pdo-функции? В if... выдает ошибку (DbException наследует \PDOException и записывает ошибки в файл)

```
namespace core\base\model;

use core\base\controller\Singleton;
use core\base\exceptions\DbException;

class BaseModel{

    use Singleton;
    protected $db;

    private function __construct()
    {
            $this->db = @new \PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', USER, PASS, DB_CONN_SETT);
        
        if($this->db->PDO::errorCode()){
            throw new DbException('Ошибка подключения к базе данных: '.$this->db->PDO::errorCode().' '.$this->db->PDO::errorInfo());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **В if... выдает ошибку** Текст ошибки секретный или нам можно поглядеть на него? Но судя по всему тебе надо `$this->db->errorCode()` и так далее.

Comment: Может я чего-то не знаю, такая запись `$this->db->PDO::errorCode()` вообще законна?) У Вас динамический класс как в статический првератился? Там же должно быть `$this->db->errorCode()`...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно без указания класса писать:

```
$this->db->errorCode()
```